# Open Cv Android : how to find all max locations of a Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv

`Core.minmaxLoc(Mat).maxLoc` returns the first location where the maximum value occurs but when in our `Mat` if maximum value is occurring on more than one places how to get all places.

Answer (score 1):

I can think two ways.

1. traverse the Mat manually.
2. if the Mat is not so big (useless after get the max lacation is better), you can clone it and use minmaxLoc() to find the first max location, then negative the value there, and find it again....